# RecyclerView: Load Another Image When First Image Has Finished Loading

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I have a recyclerviewer that reloads photo when the user scrolls. But since I have 3 photos in a row, I run into a problem:

I need to initially load 12 photos at once, to make sure the recyclerview is scrollable. And then continue to load 12 photos at once each time a scroll happens. This doesnt really feel nice. How can I have my recyclerviewer wait for the first photo to load and once this is done load the next until the screen is filled. And only when the user starts scrolling to "white spaces" more pictures start showing? This is my RecyclerViewer:

```
private void InitRecView()
        {
            mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);



            if (picturesinarow != 1)
            {
                //3 in a row
                loadPhotos.LoadMoreItems(12);//(Constants.LOADNEXTITEMSTHRESHHOLD);

            }
            else
            {
                loadPhotos.LoadMoreItems(3);
            }

            mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager
               (this, this.picturesinarow, GridLayoutManager.Vertical, false);
            mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            mAdapter = new PhotoAlbumAdapter
                (loadPhotos, this.picturesinarow, (RecyclerLayout)this.recyclerLayout, this.hasHeader, this.thumbnails, this);

            mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
            mLayoutManager.SetSpanSizeLookup(new GridViewSpansizeLookup(mAdapter, mLayoutManager));

            var onScrollListener = new XamarinRecyclerViewOnScrollListener(mLayoutManager);

            onScrollListener.LoadMoreEvent += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                int oldCount = loadPhotos.pictures.Count;

                if (picturesinarow != 1)
                {
                    //3 in a row
                    loadPhotos.LoadMoreItems(12);

                } 
                else
                {
                    loadPhotos.LoadMoreItems(2);
                }

                if (!mRecyclerView.IsComputingLayout)
                    mAdapter.NotifyItemRangeChanged(oldCount - 1, loadPhotos.pictures.Count);

            };


            mRecyclerView.AddOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
            mAdapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;

        }
```

Comment: Try using the default RecyclerView drawing cache methods  : `RecyclerView.SetItemViewCacheSize(12)`, `RecyclerView.DrawingCacheEnabled = true` and `RecyclerView.DrawingCacheQuality = DrawingCacheQuality.High`.